Microsoft Graph: re-send invitations, without modifying Event?
I've been trying to trigger a meeting organizer to resend the invitations for an Event via Graph, and I don't want to modify the event at all.  Here's what I've tried so far:

Made a "patch" call for the Event, without changing any of the event properties.  This did NOT result in the invitations getting re-sent.
Made a "patch" call for the Event, and appended a space character to the end of the Subject property. This DID result in the invitations getting re-sent; however the invitation prominently says "updated the meeting subject" at the top.

Is there a way to do this? Based on my testing, it looks like it only wants to resend invitations if it's modified in some way, but maybe there's a way to force it?
